# Erro: DataTables warning: table id=datatable-checkbox - Cannot reinitialise DataTable - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com o seguinte problema na construção de um datatable:

> DataTables warning: table id=datatable-checkbox - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

Bem, tentei usar o destroy e não obtive muito sucesso!

Código:

```
function retorna_cliente()
{
 $('.mostra_clientes .table').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 4,
  "ajax": {
    "url": url_base + "clientes",
    "type": "GET",
    "dataSrc": "",
  },
  "columns": [
    {
      "data": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+data['id']+"' name='verifica_check_box[]' id='verifica_check_box' class='flat'/>";
      }
    },
    { "data":"nome"},
    { "data":"data_nascimento"},
    { "data":"telefone"},
    { "data":"celular"},
    { "data":"cpf"},
    { "data":"endereco"},
    { "data":"email"},

  ], language: {
    "sProcessing":   "Carregando...",
    "sLengthMenu":   "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":  "Não foram encontrados resultados",
    "sInfo":         "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":    "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
    "sInfoPostFix":  "",
    "sSearch":       "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":          "",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
      "sPrevious": "Anterior",
      "sNext":     "Seguinte",
      "sLast":     "Último"
    }
  },
  "bDestroy": true,
 });
}
```

Comment: Se você quiser só reexecutar o ajax, você pode só chamar  `oTable.ajax.reload(null, false);`. `oTable` seria o objeto que é retornado por `.DataTable()`. Para destruir a tabela e recriá-la, usa `oTable.destroy();`.

Comment: @L.Albano. Fiz exatamente o que você pediu mas, não funciona o table. Os botões next e prev não funcionam.

Answer (score 1):

Já aconteceu algo parecido comigo, no caso tinham **duas inicializações** (uma geral do site e uma da tela em questão) do DataTables para a mesma tabela. Para solucionar apenas **mudei os seletores** para selecionarem tabelas diferentes.